# Making sure threading.Timer finishes before main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, callback, python-multithreading

I want to create a bunch of timers with varying delays before their callback functions are called. I also want to ensure that the main thread only exits when all the timers are done. So I join() with each Timer thread at the end of the main thread:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import threading

def callback(arg):
    some_func_that_might_take_seconds_to_return()
    print(arg)

timers = []

for i in range(5):
    # Note variable interval values.
    timer = threading.Timer(i, callback, args=(i,))
    timers.append(timer)
    timer.start()

for timer in timers:
    timer.join()
```

This works, but the problem is that in my "real" program, I might create hundreds of timers, but the vast majority of them will be expired by the time the main thread ends. As such, it seems silly to join() on a large number of already-done threads.

Ideally, callback() would remove the Timer object from the timer list. Is there a way I can make callback() figure out which Thread it's in? Another solution would be if there were a Timer.already_ran() value I could use to verify that the timer callback is already done.

Is there a way to do one of these solutions? Or another that I haven't thought of.

Comment: use `thread.is_alive()` to check if it is still running.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should consider whether it's really worth the effort to speed up the `timer.join()` loop. If there are only hundreds of threads, I would expect the loop to be quite fast (not counting the time where the main thread is simply blocking). That said, even if there's not much practical point in removing timer objects as they terminate, I do think it's still an interesting question academically.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin I think that any other method can be more complicate and not much faster then join()

Comment: I guess I messed up my test. I thought is_alive() would be False in the period of time between calling start() and the time at which the function callback occurs. I was wrong.